# Conceptual memory model of the Go language

Tags: go

I've a question to the Go programmers amongst you. I can't find information about the details of the memory model of Go. I shall try to describe my problem:

If I declare and define a variable or array in C, I know that this exists somewhere in the RAM at exactly one position with one specific address, until I do something that will change this.

This is not the case in Python: Python does the whole memory management for me, I can't be sure that my data will be located always at one position. E.g. strings are in practice immutable, even though the language suggests that they is not. This makes secure programming with sensitive data nearly impossible (or at least very impractical).

My question is: How does Go work from this perspective. Is it more like C or like Python? Or is it completely different? Is it possible to handle sensitive data as comfortably as in C?

Comment: If you want to clear the memory manually, that is, zero it before releasing it, I think it cannot be done for strings (they are immutable) but you could do it for other types like arrays, slices, etc. If you need to zero strings before releasing it, it would be better to use []byte.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note: as mention in "[Go Slices: usage and internals](http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)":

> The in-memory representation of `[4]int` is just four integer values laid out sequentially:

[image: http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals_slice-array.png]

> **Go's arrays are values**.
>
> An array variable denotes the entire array; **it is not a pointer to the first array element (as would be the case in C)**. This means that **when you assign or pass around an array value you will make a copy of its contents**.
>   (To avoid the copy you could pass a pointer to the array, but then that's a pointer to an array, not an array.)
>
> One way to think about arrays is as a sort of struct but with indexed rather than named fields: a fixed-size composite value.

If you are looking at "a pointer to an array", then you would need a *slice*.

> A slice is a descriptor of an array segment. It consists of a pointer to the array, the length of the segment, and its capacity (the maximum length of the segment).
>
> Our variable `s`, created earlier by `make([]byte, 5)`, is structured like this:

[image: http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals_slice-1.png]

For the way memory allocation work for array and slice, you can check out "[Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#allocation_new)"

> Go has two allocation primitives, the built-in functions `new` and `make`.
>   They do different things and apply to different types, which can be confusing, but the rules are simple.
>
> - Let's talk about new first. It's a built-in function that allocates memory, but unlike its namesakes in some other languages it does not initialize the memory, it only zeros it.
>     That is, `new(T)` allocates zeroed storage for a new item of type `T` and returns its address, a value of type `*T`.
>     In Go terminology, it returns a pointer to a newly allocated zero value of type `T`.
> - [allocation with `make`](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#allocation_make):  The built-in function `make(T, args)` serves a purpose different from `new(T)`. It creates slices, maps, and channels only, and it returns an initialized (not zeroed) value of type `T` (not `*T`).
>     The reason for the distinction is that **these three types represent, under the covers, references to data structures that must be initialized before use**.
>     A slice, for example, is a three-item descriptor containing a pointer to the data (inside an array), the length, and the capacity, and until those items are initialized, the slice is nil.

See more at "[Understanding Pointers and Memory Allocation](http://www.goinggo.net/2013/07/understanding-pointers-and-memory.html)".

Comment: Note to self: http://golang.org/ref/mem and http://research.swtch.com/gorace are good read too.

Answer (score 2):

The way memory is handled in Go is in between how it works in C and how it works in Python. Go gives a lot more control over memory layout than Python does—about as much as C. But Go is garbage-collected, like Python. So you don't have explicit control over the allocation and deallocation of memory.

Sometimes memory in Go can be moved around automatically. When a goroutine's stack gets full, it is copied to a larger one. Some day Go may have a copying garbage collector like Java, too. (It doesn't right now.)

So making sure sensitive data isn't left lying around in memory is probably harder in Go than in C. But in a system with virtual memory (i.e., all modern computers), there's always the possibility that your process will be swapped out and some other process will get its memory. Maybe the OS zeroes the memory first, maybe it doesn't.

But in Go, leaving sensitive values in memory is not nearly as dangerous as it is in C. Go doesn't let you access memory outside the bounds of a slice like C does with its arrays. (This is what led to the Heartbleed bug.) And when you allocate a new chunk of memory in Go, it is zeroed, so nothing can leak that way.

Comment: @grayfox, to expand on this answer... You can follow an established practice in Go and have a custom type (declared like `type SecureBuffer []byte`) with the `Erase()` method on it which would overwrite the contents of the array underlying that slice; then you document that as soon as the secure string is no longer needed, `Erase()` has to be called on it -- [playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/czrK0GgM3u).

Comment: @grayfox, but note that casting your `SecureBuffer` to `string` will *copy* bytes, and `append()`-ing to it might reallocate the memory which involves memory copying.  So the level of how this method is secure really depends on the intended level of security.  It might turn out that more involved schemes are due.